# What is the best performing string compare code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have following options to compare string (english) in a service where TPS is 200.

1) convert both string to upper case and compare.

2) pre-populate cache data with upper case and while comparing only convert input string to upper case and compare.

3) using System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

which approach will give best performance.

Comment: First, it's highly unlikely any performance difference will be noticeable in any way. It also depends highly on your usage. Create a benchmark and see for yourself. Related: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: refer to https://rhale78.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/string-equality-and-performance-in-c/

Comment: I doubt anything would beat `"a".Equals("b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. But the best way as always is to try it out yourself and do some benchmarks.